# Resize shapes from excel to powerpoint

Tags: excel, vba, powerpoint

Whenever I paste a shape from excel to VBA with the intended size, the size will always be different. To be exact, the `.Left` part.

This is a short version of my code:

```
With PPTPres.Slides(pptcel.Offset(0, -8).Value).Shapes.Paste
    .LockAspectRatio = msoFalse
    .Align msoAlignCenters, False
    .Align msoAlignMiddles, False
    .Align msoAlignLefts, True
    .Align msoAlignTops, True
    .Height = Application.InchesToPoints(5.49)
    .Width = Application.InchesToPoints(5.12)
    .Left = Application.InchesToPoints(0.8)
End With
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try somethink like this :

```
With PPPres.Slides(pptcel.Offset(0, -8).Value)
    .Shapes.Paste
    With .Shapes(.Shapes.Count)
        .LockAspectRatio = msoTrue
        .Left = 25
        .Top = 25
        .Height = 200
    End With
End With
```

Change the property settings accordingly.

Comment: Thank you for the help Leo, I've tried your method and found that the position will always be off after running it the second time. I'm trying to set the position to be 0.8 inches from the top left corner.

Comment: Apparently, all I had to do was to save the ppt after pasting it and everything was ok. Thanks for your help again Leo.